# Way to hide last dot in sentence when using text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: css, dot, ellipsis

Is there any way to hide or trunc tailing dot in sentence before ellipsis using only css?
I'd like to make something like "Foo bar method. ..." to be "Foo bar method..." but cannot find any solution. Is it even possible using only css?

Comment: No it is not possible unless you update the sentence. Because, the truncation works based on width of its element, not with the content. So it cannot identify the dot in a sentence, but if you rewrite the sentence, it may work accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I've thought so but wasn't sure

Comment: Not with css but if you really want to do this, you can remove the last dot with js.